# ¿Cómo acceder a los elementos de un arreglo para evaluarlos con if-else?

Tags: python, python-3.x, arraylist, condiciones

Tengo un problema con este ejercicio. He hecho la primera parte pero a la hora de poner las condicionales no logro obtener un buen resultado. Aquí les dejo el enunciado, de antemano les agradezco mucho su ayuda. Adjunto lo que he hecho hasta ahora. Quiero crear unas condicionales para acceder a los elementos que estan dentro de la lista y determinar su longitud(cuantos caracteres tiene cada palabra) y que una vez hecho eso clasifique las palabras, las que tienen hasta 6 caracteres valen 25 y las guarde en la lista "lpalabrascortas" y las mayores a 6 caracteres valen 50 y procede a guardarlos en la lista "lpalabraslargas". Al final se hace un conteo de todas las palabras con el valor total.

IMPLEMENTAR UN PROGRAMA QUE PROCESE LOS DATOS DE UNA LISTA, (defina una lista con **n** elementos) DE PALABRAS CONSIDERANDO LO SIGUIENTE.

**a)** Si es una palabra con una longitud de hasta 6 caracteres(corta) tendra un costo de 25.

**b)** Si es una palabra con una longitud mayor a 6 caracteres(larga) tendra un costo de 50.

**c)** Si es una palabra que sea un diminutivo, es decir que termine en "ito" "ita" "ico" "uelo" o en "illo" el costo sera de 65.

USTED DEBE CALCULAR Y MOSTRAR EL COSTO TOTAL DE LA LISTA DE PALABRAS USANDO EL VALOR ASIGNADO A CADA UNA, EL TOTAL DE NUMEROS DE PALABRAS CORTAS Y LARGAS, Y EL TOTAL DE DIMINUTIVOS

```
#DECLRAR VARIABLES CONSTANTES
Costo1=25
Costo2=50

#CREAR LISTA DESDE EL TECLADO
lpalabras = []
lpalabrascortas =[]
lpalabraslargas = []
n=int(input("¿Cuantas palabras desea ingresar a la lista? "))
for i in range(n):
palabra = input("Palabra: ")
lpalabras.append(palabra)
print("Las palabras ingresadas son: ", lpalabras)
```

Comment: ¿qué has intentado? ¿cual es tu pregunta?, no pienses que la comunidad hará tu tarea, esa es tu responsabilidad. Lee [ask] y pasa el [tour] para que entiendas la dinámica de SO. :-)

Comment: Nunca coloques código en los comentario, nadie los entiende, ¿has leido [ask] y has pasado el [tour] como te recomende? parece que no, por favor hazlo demora menos de 5 minutos, ademas edita tu pregunta y añade tu código alli.

Comment: Ballen recalco ¿has leído el enlace que te he recomendado?, es python no *Phyton*, en esos enlaces señalan que el codigo no debe mostrarse como imagen sino como texto porque los que deseamos ayudarte no queremos tipear, queremos copiar, pegar y ejecutar facilmente asi nos ahorramos tiempos y por ende la ayuda que recibiras sera en menos tiempo, por otro lado **¿cual es tu pregunta?**

Comment: Aun no me responde **¿cual es tu pregunta?** **¿Has intentado algo?**, en SO te ayudamos a resolver problemas, no haremos tu trabajo, asi que intenta algo y cuando tengas un poblema real crea una pregunta señalandolo claramente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

me parecio interesante tu problema, primero que nada algo de explicacion:

**Longitud de un string:**

Para obtener la longitud de un string en tu caso usamos la funcion len:

```
palabra = "elefante"
total_string = len(palabra)
print total_string
#ouput
8
```

lo que hace el len es contar la longitud de caracteres de tu palabra, con esto mediante un if podemos asignar al array respectivo cada palabra.

**Recorriento un array:**
Para recorrer un array seria mediante un ciclo for:

```
#declarando el array
#supongamos que tengo un listado de animales algo asi
listado = ['gato', 'elefante', 'tigre']
#recorriendo el array
for animal in listado:
 print animal
#output
gato
elefante
tigre
```

como vemos asi de sencillo recorro un array.
bien ahora el codigo completo de tu ejercicio:

```
#DECLRAR VARIABLES CONSTANTES
Costo1=25
Costo2=50

#CREAR LISTA DESDE EL TECLADO
lpalabras = []
lpalabrascortas =[]
lpalabraslargas = []
n=int(input("¿Cuantas palabras desea ingresar a la lista? "))
for i in range(n):
  palabra = input("Palabra: ")
  lpalabras.append(palabra)

#costos y totales
costo_palabracorta = 0
costo_palabralarga = 0

total_palabracorta = 0
total_palabralarga = 0

for palabra in lpalabras:
  longitud_palabra = len(palabra)

  if longitud_palabra <=6:

    #total palabras cortas
    total_palabracorta +=1
    #agregando solo palabras cortas
    lpalabrascortas.append(palabra)
    #costo palabras cortas
    costo_palabracorta +=Costo1

  if longitud_palabra > 6:

    #agregando palabras largas
    lpalabraslargas.append(palabra)
    #total palabras largas
    total_palabralarga +=1
    #costo palabras largas
    costo_palabralarga +=Costo2

print ("*********RESULTADO***********")
print ("Palabras Largas  ingresadas :")
if lpalabraslargas:
  for palabra_larga in lpalabraslargas:
    print (palabra_larga)
else:
  print ("sin palabras largas ingresadas")

if lpalabrascortas:
  print ("Palabras Cortas  ingresadas :")
  for palabra_corta in lpalabrascortas:
    print (palabra_corta)
else:
  print ("sin palabras cortas ingresadas")
print ("*****************************")
print ("* Total palabras largas: ",total_palabralarga)
print ("* Costo palabras largas: ",costo_palabralarga)
print ("*****************************")
print ("* Total palabras cortas: ",total_palabracorta)
print ("* Costo palabras cortas: ",costo_palabracorta)
print ("******************************")
print ("* Costo total: $",costo_palabralarga+costo_palabracorta)
```

**Captura de resultado:**
[image: resultado]

Espero te sirva y te pueda guiar...solo debes ser constante..recuerda en la programacion es asi..error..tras ..error hasta que obtengas lo deseado..solo te faltaria el literal **C**..suerte !!

Comment: para el diminutivo podrias usar un if...algo asi:...if "ito"  in palabra: .....

Comment: Muchas gracias viejo, era exactamente lo que necesitaba esclarecer. Salud por mas héroes sin capa como tu